# Make Klazuka/Kal Controller Dates Unselectable?

Tags: iphone, calendar

i use [Klazuka/Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) controller for selection dates.
is it possible to make disable dates before today? i want to make earlier dates in different color too.

Answer (score 0):

To change color for selected date

Go to --> KalTileView.h file

in - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect method

```
 [[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Kal.bundle/kal_tile_today_selected.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:6 topCapHeight:0] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, -1, kTileSize.width+1, kTileSize.height+1)];      // change your image name and put your mentioned image to Kal.bundle package
textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

that solve

Comment: i want users not to select earlier date from now. earlier dates must be shown disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ***KalGridView.m*** & replace **-(void)setSelectedTile:(KalTileView *)tile** with code given below.

```
- (void)setSelectedTile:(KalTileView *)tile
{
    if (selectedTile != tile && [[KalDate dateFromNSDate:[NSDate date]] compare:tile.date] != NSOrderedDescending) 
    {
        selectedTile.selected = NO;
        selectedTile = [tile retain];
        tile.selected = YES;
        [delegate didSelectDate:tile.date];
    }
}
```

And now all those dates prior to current date will be disabled.